# Xml validation Error Eclipse Crash Deployment of App

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

What is the error, here?

[image: Hello Everybody, What is the error, here?]

The problem is that my whole deployment crash for this. When show details it says:

> src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'jboss:enterprise-beans' to a(n)
> 'element declaration' component.

Adiccionally says too:

"The errors below were detected when validating the file "**jboss-ejb3-spec-2_0.xsd**"
via file "**handler.xml**". In most cases there errors can be detected by validating "jboss-**ejb3-spec-2_0.xsd**" directly. However it is possible that errors will only occur when **jboss-ejb3-spec-2_0.xsd** is validated in the context of **handler.xml**"

Answer (score 0):

Seems your file is missing [namespace declarations](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.1/html/apache_cxf_development_guide/jaxwshandlersconfig#JAXWSHandlersConfigServerFileEx)

```
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- handler-chain elements -->

</handler-chains>
```